# How can one characterize all linear functionals on random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite expectation?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

This question was completely restated to make it well-posed and understandable.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the algebra of random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite expectation. By a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ with finite expectation I mean a Lesbegue-measurable probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, such that $\left| \int  x \mu(x) dx  \right|<\infty$ and an index $\nu \in \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is some set (let it be countable), that enumerates different random variables with the same distribution. Note that random variables with all possible distributions with finite expectation on $\mathbb{R}$ belong to this algebra, including singular distributions. The random variables defined above are the basis for a free commutative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, factored by coincidence almost surely. The field $\mathbb{R}$ is injected in this algebra via a map $u: r \to \delta_{r}$, where $\delta_{r}$ denotes a constant random variable with value $r$. Since the algebra is factored by coincidence a.s., all independent identically distributed random variables $\delta_{r}$ with the same $r$ are exactly the same random variable (as opposed to just having the same distribution).

Given this preset, how do I describe all linear functionals on $\mathcal{C}$, if I want them to not discern identically distributed random variables (i.e. a given linear functional has the same value on any random variable with a given distribution)? In other words, what are all such functionals $L$ that, given a pair of **independent** identically distributed random variables $X, X'$,
$$L(X+X')=L(X)+L(X')=2L(X)=L(2X)$$

**Edit:**
If we assume that the functional acts on distributions and has the form $L[f(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x)f(x)$, then, substituting delta-functions into the integral equation

$$L[f(x)]+L[g(x)]=L[f*g(x)]$$

we obtain $\rho(x)+\rho(y)=\rho(x+y)$. Hence, an affine transform of expectation is the only option with such constraints (assuming $\rho$ is at least piecewise continuous). However, this tells nothing about more general functionals.

Comment: All linear functionals on the set of *all* random variables, or on the set of random variables with finite expectation?

Comment: With finite expectation

Answer (score 3):

The set of all random variables on a probability space $\Omega$ with finite expectation is just $L^1(\Omega)$. It seems you are looking for the algebraic dual of this space. I am not sure what this is to be honest and I can imagine it is a very large space consisting of some very pathological objects.

The topological dual on the other hand, i.e. the space of all continuous linear functions (continuity defined with respect to the norm on $L^1(\Omega)$), is well-understood, and is given by $L^\infty(\Omega)$. To be more precise, given any $Y \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, the map $L^1(\Omega) \ni X \mapsto \mathbb{E}[XY] \in \mathbb{R}$ is linear and continuous as a map from $L^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ and, furthermore, for any such linear, continuous map $F:L^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a $Y \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $F(X)=\mathbb{E}[XY]$.

Comment: Note that random variables and their distributions are not the same thing. Distributions of random variables don't form a linear space; instead, they form a convolution ring. Also note that $L^{1}(\Omega)$ does not contain singular distributions, and not every element of $L^{1}$ is a probability distribution. So $L^{1}$ is neither a subspace of the space of probability distributions (with finite expectation), nor does it contain all of them.

Comment: I think you are a bit confused or maybe I did not explain it well enough: I am not referring to the distributions of random variables but to the random variables themselves. Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, a random variable is a measurable function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. The space of all random variables with finite expectation is $exactly$ $L^1(\Omega)$. To see this note that $\mathbb{E}[X] <\infty$ iff $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$ (this is a property of the Lebesgue integral) and the constraint $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$ is exactly what gives you $L^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: The other answer by @user469053 explains stuff in detail. Have a look at it.

Comment: @ almosteverywhere please, edit your comment so that I can upvote it

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku As this and the deleted answer have already told you, the dual of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku edited